# Which encoding does dbm use to save data to bytes(python(And how to convert it back to a string?))?

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, dbm

I mean that which type of encoding does dbm use in coding string to bytes?
And how to convert it back to a string?

Comment: I mean like utf-8, aiise etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you mean [encoding](https://techterms.com/definition/encoding). So, a `**dbm**` database can only store strings, both as keys and values. In fact, it only stores bytes, and by default uses your default encoding if you give it Unicode strings.

You can test your system default encoding through:

**For UNIX-based:**

```
echo $LC_CTYPE
```

or

```
echo $LANG
```

**For Windows using `PowerShell`:**

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

Comment: well, what does that mean?

Comment: dbm doesn't perform any encryption, it just encodes Strings into bytes using default system encoding (where every system has default type of encoding, it is about how to convert bytes to string and vice versa), please follow the link in the answer in order to know more about it

Comment: The commands you wrote in your answer doesn't check; they just raise that old ms-dos error

Comment: what is your current OS?

Comment: windows 8.1 is my os